# jQuery Calculate window yScroll position

Tags: jquery, scroll, coordinates

I'm trying to calculate they y position of the scrollbar dynamically as the window scrolls. I can get the initial scroll position on load using:

```
var scrollY = $(window).scrollTop();
```

But this doesn't update as the window scrolls around, I need to reload each time to get the updated variable. What do I need to do to keep this value updating as I scroll? I've tried something like:

```
$(document).scroll(function(e){
    $('#status').html(e.scrollY);
});
```

And then created a div with and ID of 'status' to output the result, but I'm getting nothing. Can anyone assist with this?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why do you think that the `scrollTop` doesn't update as the window scrolls? When I try it, it works just fine:

CSS:

```
#status { height: 1000px; padding: 100px; }
```

Script:

```
$(document).scroll(function(e){
    $('#status').html($(window).scrollTop());
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="status"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Z4sZp/